# hide ui datepicker on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I think this is not working because its performing the mouseout on the input. But how would I select the current instance of the datepicker to add the hide method?

```
$("input.datePicker").datepicker().mouseout(function() {
    $(this).datepicker("hide");    
});
```

Comment: Can you show the ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) mark-up, or provide a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, live demo for us to test with? Help *us* to help *you*.

Comment: try this ... $("input.datePicker").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).datepicker("hide");    
});

Comment: @suresh.g that will hide the picker if you mouse-out off the input - I think the OP wants to hide the picker if you mouse-out off the picker itself

Comment: Jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/nBmcY/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to target the `datepicker` class itself as the selector:

```
$('.ui-datepicker').mouseleave(function(){
    $("input.datePicker").datepicker('hide').blur()

});
```

Since the datepicker is dynamically generated this needs to be called after initialization of the widget.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nBmcY/2/

EDIT: Added trigger blur of input also so user can immediately click same field if mistake made.